# Why Developing countries, especially exporters are most vulnerable to strong US Dollar?

Tags: international-trade, international-economics, foreign-exchange

> Developing countries, especially exporters such as Argentina and
> Turkey, are among the most vulnerable, says Harvard economics
> professor Jeffrey Frankel.

Excerpt from: https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-06-23/us-dollar-strength-sparks-currency-war-to-tame-inflation

I think, exporters should benefit from stronger USD, as their exports are more competitive now due to weaker currency at home.

Comment: In which sense are they vulnerable? For me the link is behind a pay-wall.

Comment: Doesn't the article itself answer that? (A lot of emerging economies have more debt denominated in dollars than they do in their own currencies, he says: “That’s the worst of all worlds—to have your currency depreciate against the dollar when you have dollar debt.”)